# Wht is Google Apps Script to fill word template from form not working for me

Tags: templates, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

Following Jeff Everharts tutorial, I wrote a test script to fill a docs template from a form response. My efforts have been frustrated because no matter what I try the script will not replace any of the text in my body, even though I have removed all formatting and used the double curly brackets as instructed. My code generates a new document in the correct folder, and the title of that document which includes my variable zero is correct. Only no text is ever modified. Any idea as to why? I'm wondering if the values from the form are somehow not being saved as text, or if the template document needs some kind of permission activated to be modified. Your suggestions would be most welcome!

```
``
function autofillgoogledocfromform(e) {
  var zero = e.values[0];
  var one = e.values[1];

  var templateFile = DriveApp.getFileById("1lcaeliMu3xP2L0--YJMSeLFY1uHq81-1g7rXvgIryfY");
  var templateresponsefolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1bVSRMV_NGI9J2RzWhOMekT77yLtKDjGd");

  var copy = templateFile.makeCopy(zero, templateresponsefolder);
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getID());
  var text = doc.getBody();
  
  body.replaceText ('{{one}}', one);
  body.replaceText('{{zero}}', zero);
  body.appendParagraph("A paragraph.");

  doc.saveAndClose();
}


``
```

I tried modifying the template text to be without brackets, with or without formatting, amd at the top of the document to no effect. I also tried changing the entry into body.replaceText to be with or without the brackets and paratheses.

Answer (score 1):

In the code you have given here, you are taking a variable named text

```
var text = doc.getBody();
```

However in the next 3 lines you are using a different variable named 'body' , so I suggest you to change the variable 'text' to 'body' like mentioned below

```
var body = doc.getBody();
```

Hope that will solve it, Let me know if it still doesn't work